# Move object with different speed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an object which is going up all the time. I want my object to go up at certain speed at first then with another speed after that (say, after 5 seconds). I am simply using

```
transform.Translate (Vector3.up * speed, Space.World);
```

but it's only going up at same speed all the time which I don't want.

Comment: Have you attempted to code a solution to this problem yourself? Please include the relevant code showing your best attempt at it.

Comment: actually I have no idea how to do that.that's the best I could do.@Serlite

Comment: Have you tried simply changing the speed after 5 seconds?

Comment: @solo365 You should look at the details of asking questions (Looking at all your other questions) first here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
The Unity documentation covers this and most of your questions already. I found the answer to this by googling "speed over time unity"

Comment: Sounds like you want acceleration/deceleration. The key is to gradually change `speed`. See [this](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/82281) question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply change the speed after 5 seconds.

Your class would look like this:

```
public IEnumerator Start() {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
    speed *= 2;
}

public void Update() {
    transform.Translate(Vector3.up * speed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
}
```

It's important that you add `* Time.deltaTime` to your translation calculation because otherwise your actual speed will be different from one machine to another.

> If you add or subtract to a value every frame chances are you should multiply with Time.deltaTime. When you multiply with Time.deltaTime you essentially express: I want to move this object 10 meters per second instead of 10 meters per frame.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html

Comment: Thank you so much @sokkyoku